# Linux Mint 5.15.0-47-generic "error: out of memory" when booting

Tags: linux-mint, boot, memory, nvidia

This error started showing up after having installed the Nvidia proprietary drivers and restarted my computer.

I cannot get past it except by rebooting, going into the boot options, and then choosing Linux 5.15.0-41-generic.

[error: out of memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhXqj.jpg)

[following error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BelOo.jpg)

[Linux Mint boot options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Sccy.jpg)

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: HFM512GD3JX013N                         
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F48ABFC7-7FE3-4420-9066-CE3173A5459F

Device           Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 1000214527 999163904 476.4G Linux filesystem
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solved it for me: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1842320/comments/17

1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Uncomment `GFX_MODE` and set it equal to `800x600`
3. `sudo update-grub`

**EDIT**: The solution mentioned by @mortona42 in the comments worked for me with Linux Mint Vera 21.10.

1. `sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`
2. Set `MODULES=dep`
3. Set `COMPRESS=xz`
4. `sudo update-initramfs -u`

I did this in conjunction with the `GFX_MODE` workaround, so I don't know whether they are both working together or whether only the latter is doing the heavy lifting.

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub` after changing that config. I had to lower it to 640x480.
A better fix is to change MODULE=deps and COMPRESSION=xz in in initramfs.conf and run `sudo update-initramfs -u`.

Comment: @mortona42 I added `update-grub` to the answer, thank you. However, I haven't tried your solution. If you wish, post it as an answer for other people to see.

Comment: This really saved my life! For those like me unable to boot from any kernel, you might need to run `update-grub` and `update-initramfs` from a LiveUSB, following [this procedure](https://askubuntu.com/a/145253/173974) for example.

Comment: Just setting `COMPRESS=xz` and running `sudo update-initramfs -u -k <my-kernel-version>` solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the initramfs for the kernel.

1. Boot into the kernel that works.
2. Open a terminal and type `sudo update-initramfs -u -k 5.15.0-47-generic`.
3. When the command has finished, type `sudo update-grub`.
4. Reboot.

Comment: Do you still get the same error?

Comment: yes, still the same error.

Comment: Boot into a kernel that works and type `sudo fdisk -l`, copy the output and edit your post to include the copied output.

Comment: there it is, done.

Comment: @AnotherSherlock Sorry, I totally forgot about this. I see that you managed to solve it. I'll upvote your solution for visibility.

Comment: don't worry about it!