# Kernel panic when booting new kernels

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, kernel-panic

I'm running Linux Mint 21.1 Xfce and it was all good up to and including 5.15.0-60-generic but after updating to -67 I started getting an "out of memory" error at boot (hit any key) followed by "kernel panic, not syncing, VFS unable to mount rootfs on unknown block".

Booting trusty old version -60 via advanced options worked fine so I figured I'd just skip -67 and wait until the next version. But now -69 is out and doing the same thing. So a bit of Googling turned up these:

https://www.geekswarrior.com/2019/07/solved-how-to-fix-kernel-panic-on-linux.html

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=338544

So I tried this:

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
update-initramfs -u -k 5.15.0-69-generic
update-grub2
```

But only ended up losing my Windows Grub entry and -69 STILL won't boot. It's fairly new hardware (13700K, DDR5, 4070 Ti) so I wondered if that has anything to do with it, but it works fine on -60 and earlier? I'm happy enough to stick with an older kernel for now, but eventually that's going to become a undesirable security-wise if I'm way out-of-date.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a regression. Does kernel 6.2.8 work for you?

Comment: Well I tend to play it safe and only install the Ubuntu kernels offered by Mint updater (I'm not somebody who gets excited about new kernel versions - just want to stay secure). So 5.15 branch is as new as I'm offered. I guess I could manually install something more cutting edge though if it's really necessary?

Comment: Suit yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a related answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/717710

It says to modify `MODULES` and `COMPRESS` in `initramfs.conf`

Using an editor of your choice (you will need to do this with `sudo` privilege)-

Set `MODULES=dep`
Set `COMPRESS=xz`

Execute `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Comment: That did it! Thank you! Yeah I have those nVIDIA drivers too...